# Which sources should one refer to verify spelling according to UK English?

Tags: discussion, resource-request

Apologies if this is off-topic here. I was unsure where to ask it. Please migrate to the main site if it is on-topic there. If it is not on-topic in both the main site as well as here, please close it.

Problem: When I try to "google" or "bing" a particular word, most of the time it shows me the word according to the US English. I find it hard to find the word according to the UK English even in some of the dictionaries.

Where may I refer to the words according to the UK English?

Comment: Try [Dictionary of the British English Spelling System by Greg Brooks](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=sgh2CAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

Comment: Thanks @void It looks good. Price is reasonable as well.

Comment: You [don't have to pay](https://www.openbookpublishers.com/product/325). (Click the 'download' next to PDF in the link and then click **'here'** in the last sentence .... 'To download this book please click here'.)

Comment: There aren't that many words which are spelt (spelled) differently in British English. A few verbs such as *dream*, *learn*, and *spell* are irregular in BrEng. On Wikipedia there are a few lists of different spelling when words are pronounced differently in both countries or have slightly different meanings https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences